# How to automatic deleting files to a folder in ubuntu?

Tags: file, ubuntu, directory, ubuntu-10.04, delete-file

**How to  automatic deleting files to a folder in ubuntu?**

I need to do a script to delete files from a folder that is filled with the execution of a process on my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper command would be `rm -rf folder/` to delete files recursively from that particular folder.

Answer (score 2):

If `rm folder/*` isn't the answer you seek, could you clarify your question?